# How to pass values from the main to private

Tags: c++

I've read about classes and how private and public work, but I'm still stumped on how to implement them.

What I'm trying to do is pass 2 integers from main to a private class that are user defined for row and column. Then using the row and column the 2d array is filled with integers 0 to row*column-1 and saved in a function inside private.

Finally it is initialized by a function in the public.

My question is how do I pass 2 integers from the main to the private? Would I have to make a function in the public to do so? If so how?

```
#include <vector>

class Example {

public:

    void displayArray() {
        for (int row = 0; row < T_array.size(); ++row) {
            for (int col = 0; col < T_array[row].size(); ++col) {
             // print stuff
            }
        }
    }

private:

void fillArray(int rows, int columns) {
    T_array.resize(rows);
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
        T_array[row].resize(columns);
        for (int col = 0; col < columns; ++col) {
            T_array[row][col] = ...
        }
    }
}

std::vector<std::vector<int>> T_array;   // Nested vector for 2D
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how do I pass 2 integers from the main to the private? Would I have to make a function in the public to do so?

Yes you have to make it `public` that the class member function can be called from `main()`.

> If so how?

Like so

```
public: // Or just omit the private

void fillArray(int rows, int columns) {
     // ...
}
```

Your member variables can stay `private` though (if this should be your concern):

```
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> T_array;   // Nested vector for 2D
```

Answer (score 0):

Private data con only be modified by a methods of the same class so your choices are:

- Implement a private method that fills the value... but then this private method needs to be called from other method of the same class
- Implement a protected method that fills the value... but this protected method must be called from the same class or from a derived class.
- Implement a public method that fills the value. Well, this method can be called from anywhere.

Your choice depends on the structure of the rest of the code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input without telling me the answer directly. I think I now know how to implement my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access private class members from outside a class, that is the point of private. (I know, friends can, but that doesn't apply here.)

So when you define a class you have to make up your mind:

Should your member be accessible from outside the class? -> Make it public.

If not -> private.